# Error when accessing API with discord.js, but only on an embed?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a Discord bot which gets data from the Hypixel API, an API for a Minecraft server. I have managed to write some code which successfully gets the data, but this is where I am running into an issue. When I directly `message.channel.send` the data, it works. However, if I use the data in an embed, it doesn't work.

Does work:

```js
fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=API_KEY&name=${args[1]}`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(({ player }) => {

      message.channel.send(player.stats.Bedwars.coins)
})
```

Does not work:

```js
fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=API_KEY&name=${args[1]}`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(({ player }) => {

      var bedwars_general_1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .addFields(
          { name: 'Coins', value: player.stats.Bedwars.coins, inline: true},
      )
      
      message.channel.send(bedwars_general_1)
})
```

With the top example, it works perfectly, however with the bottom one, I get this error message every single time:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Bedwars' of undefined
```

It also gives me this error when I added this line
`var bedwarsCoins = player.stats.Bedwars.coins`, before the embed and then added the variable to the embed field.

I cannot understand why it only works some of the time?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `stats` property of `player` is undefined or null.

It's possible that the API couldn't find anything, which in that case you should try catching the absence of a value of the `stats` property.

```
.then(player => {
  if (!player.stats) return console.log('Unable to find stats');
});
```

Comment: The problem is, is that there is a `stats` property of player, which can be seen if you use the API. This is also shown by the fact that the `message.channel.send(player.stats.Bedwars.coins)` also works. It is just that it doesn't work in the embed for some reason?

Comment: Try changing `.addFields({ name: 'Coins', value: player.stats.Bedwars.coins, inline: true})`
to just `.addField('Coins', player.stats.Bedwars.coins, true)`